# how to parse jQuery address plugin

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, jquery

i am using http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/    plugin and trying to parse some url, this is what i got:

```
<script>$(function(){
      $.address.init(function(event) {

                // Initializes the plugin
                $('a').address();

            }).change(function(event) {

 $('a').attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');

    $.ajax({
  url: 'items.php',
  data:"data="+event.value,
  success: function(data) {
    $('div#content').html(data)

      }
   })

});


})</script>
```

then HTML:

```
<a href="items.php?id=2">link02</a>
<a href="items.php?id=3">link03</a>
```

then im calling item.php, wich for now only has

```
echo $_GET["data"];
```

so after the ajax request has complete it echoes :

```
/items.php?id=2
/items.php?id=3
```

how can i parse this so i get only the var values? it is better to do it on client side?
and also if my html href is something like  `<a href="items.php?id=2&var=jj">link02</a>`
jQuery address will ignore the `&var=jj`

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the query string and then [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the query string parsed into variables.

Example:

```
<?php

// this is your url
$url = 'items.php?id=2&var=jj';

// you ask parse_url to parse the url and return you only the query string from it
$queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

// parse_str can extract the variables into the global space or can put them into an array
// NOTE: for simplicity no validation is performed but in production you should perform validation
$params = array();
parse_str($queryString, $params);
// you can access the values like thid
echo $params['id']; // will output 2
echo $params['var']; // will output 'jj'
// I prefer this way, because it eliminates the posibility of overwriting another global variable
// with the same name as one of the parameters in the url.

// or you can tell parse_str to extract the variables into the global space
parse_str($queryString);
// or if you want to use the global scope
echo $id; // will output 2
echo $var; // will output 'jj'
```

Comment: Thank you i was trying this but with little succes.